# How can I get an instruction's XCM base weight for Kusama and other substrate chains through Polkadot JS?

Tags: xcm, weight, fee, weighttofee

I can get instruction's XCM base weight [from code](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/v0.9.37/runtime/kusama/src/weights/xcm/pallet_xcm_benchmarks_fungible.rs#L49-L53) (for example, WithdrawAsset instruction), but I can't found how to get this value from PolkadotJS. How can I get an instruction's XCM base weight for Kusama from PolkadotJS? Or what useful information can I get for calculating XCM weights and fees from PolkadotJS?